# Javascript canvas not being cleaned

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

I must ask for help due to this code:

```
    <head>
     <title>Rectangles</title>

      <style> 
         body {
        background: #dddddd;
     }

     #canvas {
        background: #eeeeee;
        border: thin solid #aaaaaa;
     }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id='canvas' width="578" height="200">
  Canvas not supported
</canvas>
<br>
<button type="button"id="disminuir" onclick="disminuir()">Girar CCW</button> 
<button type="button"id="aumentar" onclick="aumentar()">Girar CW</button> 

<script src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this javascript:

Well, actually it's not acting as suposed mainly because each time you redraw the box, the canvas is not cleared...

```
var context;
var rectWidth = 64;
var rectHeight = 64;
var rotation;
rotation=0;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);


draw();


   function draw() { 

            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);    
            context.strokeRect(-rectWidth / 2, -rectHeight / 2, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            context.rotate(rotation * 1 * Math.PI / 180);


    }     

function aumentar()
{
 rotation=rotation+0.5;
 draw();
}

function disminuir()
{
  rotation=rotation-0.5;
  draw();
}
```

You can find all this in:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0371ad6ec1bbfabed80a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use clearRect

```
   context.save(); // save state
   context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // set to indentity
   context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clear
   context.restore();  // restore state
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nuk4mnrw/